# I need to auto-count UNIQUE values within a range of formula output which may or may not be blank

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I need a formula which will automate the following logic:

Columns J16:z200 holds values to populate based on an IF Statement.  All of them have formulas, some of them have output of a zipcode, and some of them are blank.

The intended goal is to capture the number of unique zip codes within a county that is providing sales leads for a sales team...typical counting formulae don't filter for duplicates so I ended up with:

**=SUMPRODUCT(((J16:J199<>"")/COUNTIF(J16:J199, J16:J199 &"")))**

...which seemed to work until I went to validate the data, which is where it gets weird.  In the image (it's a really large spreadsheet so I'm just giving you a snapshot of the relevant fields)

1-the gray line is the tally of the number of leads in a county

2-the pink line is the tally (supposedly) of unique zipcodes within that county

Line2 should always be equal or less than line 1... no exceptions...but, if you look down at the county count outputs, you can see that the tally output is not accurate.  And worse than that, it's right in some places, and wrong in others/off by 1, which makes ZERO sense.

[page snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3oSM.png)

Each of the white fields has a formula similar to this =IF(AND($B$16="County",J3="County"),$E$16,"")

Each column with a different county name plugged into where it says "County"

I'm thoroughly confused.

[Snippet 2 - using frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0isB.png)

Comment: I tested your **SUMPRODUCT** formula which is returning the correct result as the one I suggested. Please clarify what is the formula you used in the pink line?

Comment: The pink line IS that sumproduct formula.

Answer (score 0):

Presume in the white cells you will either have a numerical value (zip code) or blank returned by a formula,

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(FREQUENCY(I3:I12,I3:I12)>0,1))
```

A useful link for you: [Count unique values among duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)

Comment: This formula came back with output of 0 on a range with 4 zip codes in it.  (See the 2nd snippet I added above)

Comment: @Ali your zip code may not be number even though they looks like one. Can you try to add this `=--(TRIM(your formula))` to the formula you have in the white cells?

Comment: That trim was suggested by one of my cohorts here and that was the key.  I added TRIM to the end of the IF statement and it fixed the whole page.